# How to use multiprocessing in a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am new to Python `multiprocessing`. I have a function that returns values and is supposed to act in parallel. In the following, you can find a sample code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

def foo(self):
    arg_triplets = [(self.loc_x[ii], self.loc_y[jj], self.arg) 
                    for ii in np.arange(0, self.nx) for jj in np.arange(0, self.ny)]
    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    max_proc = mp.cpu_count()-1
    pool = ctx.Pool(processes=max_proc)
    return_values = list(tqdm(pool.imap(target_foo, arg_triplets), total=nx*ny))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So, when I run this routine once, everything works fine. The function `target_foo` takes triplets of arguments and returns all the output values as a list. I can monitor the status of my 8 core processor, and see 7 of them are working simultaneously. But the problem starts when I use function `foo` in a `for` loop. For example, I need to gather data for multiple `foo` which I do not need in parallel. So I create a `for` loop that calls `foo` sequentially. In each call of `foo`, the function `target_foo` is supposed to work in parallel. The problem is that for the first time it works on parallel, but from the second time, it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently I did not understand what exactly the problem is.